# How do i convert Grid View in List View inside fragment?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, fragment

[This is what I am trying to build](https://lh6.ggpht.com/Ly21pAbBRIxAzHn2R119a37NexxtjG5RkQJV8vv0IoCywzksIhKNSCkzWikbUnH8bGY=h900-rw)

I don't know how to do this using **ImageButton** or **tabs**. Can I change layout of the fragment at run-time? Or should I use 2 different fragments?

Comment: It is a card view and recycler view that you are viewing in your screenshot. Search for card view and recycler view on google you will find many tutorials to acheve this.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `RecyclerView` and set its layout manager for listView. Use `LinearLayoutManager` and for grid view you have to use `GridLayoutManager`

```
    RecyclerView recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);


    //this is for list view
    //    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

     //this is fro grid view
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```